# Localizing my display name attribute but can't reference my resource

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, localization, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to localize my display name attribute but "ResourceType" can't find my resource file. Resource file is directly in my solution.

[image]

Also set my access modifier to public but still not working.

[image: Also set my access modifier to public but still not working.]

I can't even see it.

[image]

Comment: Try right-clicking on the resx and select the "run custom tool option" I encountered this weird behavior of VS sometimes not generating the .cs file corresponding to the resx when saving it, this forces it to do it. And also do you have a `DisplayName.resx` resource file in your solution? if not, try removing the .en, it should then behave as the default one, add the language codes for specific locales after that.

Comment: Removing the ".en" worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'll just post that as an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue is that you are specifying a locale for the resource file without having a default one present in your solution.

`DisplayName.resx` would be the default language of your application and is needed for the resolution mechanism to work

`DisplayName.<locale code>.resx` will then override the default locale resources for that particular locale.